# got json_code data when use dump die, but return illegal offset when returning to view laravel

Tags: json, laravel, api, guzzle

I'm using guzzle to access API that i've made, I want to return the value of the this json_decode

```
    public function edit($id)
    {

    $client = new Client();
    $response = $client->request('GET', '103.200.4.97:9090/api/v1/content/'.$id);

    $body = $response->getBody();
    $data = json_decode($body, true);

    return view('content.edit-content', compact('data'));

    }
```

when i dump die the json_decode with `dd($data);` i got the json value, but when i want to return that value to view with compact, *i got error illegal offset string 'id'*

this is my view looks like

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<form method="post" action="{{ url('/update_content') }}">
    @csrf
    @foreach ($data as $item)

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="thumbnail_url">Thumbnail URL</label>
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $item['id'] }}">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="thumbnail_url" placeholder="Enter Thumbnail url" name="thumbnail_url" value="{{ $item['thumbnail_url'] }}">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="image_url">Image URL</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="image_url" placeholder="Enter Image" name="image_url" value="{{ $item['image_url'] }}">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="category_id">Category id</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="category_id" placeholder="Enter Category" name="category_id" value="{{ $item['category_id'] }}">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">Title</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="Enter Title" name="title" value="{{ $item['title'] }}">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="description">Description</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="description" placeholder="Enter Description" name="description" value="{{ $item['description'] }}">
    </div>

    @endforeach
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>

@endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one.

```php
public function edit($id)
{

    $data= Client::where('id',$id)->first();

    return view('content.edit-content', ['data' => $data]);

}
```

Comment: when i use the first one, i got an error Undefined index: id, and when i use the second one it return the same error illegal offset string 'id'

Comment: @Villian Updated.

Comment: for the first one i got an error undefined offset 1, and for the second one i got an error undefined offset 1

Comment: i've already figure this out, i use foreach to call a single data which is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Add get contents to your response body

```
$data = json_decode($response->getBody());
return view('content.edit-content', ['data'=> $data->data]);
```

in your html:

```
@foeach($data as $d)
 ...
 {{ $d->id }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: still got the same error illegal offset string 'id'

Comment: i still got the same error illegal offset string 'id'

Comment: @Villian can you post the sample data from your die dump

Comment: ** array:2 [▼
  "status" => "success"
  "data" => array:9 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "thumbnail_url" => "ini adalah thumbnail"
    "image_url" => "ini adalah image url"
    "category_id" => 1
    "title" => "ini adalah title"
    "description" => "ini adalah deskripsi"
    "status" => "1"
    "created_at" => "2019-11-06 15:02:28"
    "updated_at" => "2019-11-06 15:02:28"
  ]
] **

Comment: it still got the same error illegal offset string 'id'

Comment: i've already figure this out, i use foreach to call a single data which is wrong